# How to permute 2 cells of a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, cell

I'd like to do a small function that would permute 2 cells of a table with jQuery (or PHP/Ajax).
Let's say I have the following table:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="btn" data-cellN="1">
            01
        </td>
        <td class="btn" data-cellN="2">
            02
        </td>          
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="btn" data-cellN="3">
            05
        </td>
        <td class="btn" data-cellN="4">
            06
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to select 2 cells and permute them?

EDIT:

I made my way through the function thanks to your advice, nevertheless. It is working the first time bug I got a weird bug coming from the c1 c2 c3 variables, I don't know why,
could anyone help me to finish my function please?

Here is my Javascript: (it is wrapped in a doc ready)

```
        var nbbuttonclicked=0; // to trigger the movecell function after the second button was clicked
        var count=0; //Number of tinme we moved a cell

        var table = {

            c1:null,
            c2:null,
            c3:null,

            check: function(){
                $('td').on('click', function(){ //When the user click on a button we verify if he already clicked on this button

                    if( $(this).hasClass('btn-info') ) {

                        //If yes, then remove the class and variable c1
                        $(this).removeClass('btn-info');
                        table.c1=0;
                        nbbuttonclicked--;

                    }else{
                        //if no, then add a class to show him it is clicked and remember the value of the cell
                        $(this).addClass('btn-info');
                        if( typeof table.c1 === 'undefined' || table.c1===null) {
                            table.c1 = $(this);
                          console.log('c1:'+table.c1.html());
                        }else{
                            table.c2 = $(this);
                          console.log('c2:'+table.c2.html());
                        }

                        nbbuttonclicked++;

                        if( nbbuttonclicked==2 ) {
                            table.movecell(table.c1,table.c2); // we trigger the function to permute the values
                        }
                    }
                });
            },

            movecell: function(c1, c2){
                //We reset that variable for the next move
                nbbuttonclicked=0;

              //we move the cells
              table.c3=c1.html();
              c1.html(c2.html());
              c2.html(table.c3)

              c1.removeClass('btn-info');
              c2.removeClass('btn-info');
              table.c1=table.c2=table.c3=c1=c2=null;

            },

            // movecell: function(c1, c2){
                // We check if the cells.html() are = to data-cellN. If yes, you won
                // foreach()
            // },

            // var row = $('table tr:nth-child(1)')[0];
            // moveCell(row, 0, 3);
        };
        table.check();
```

and here is a sample: 
http://jsbin.com/exesof/2/edit

Comment: You mean when you change table values also its affects into db?

Comment: I think he means to merge them, but am not sure xD

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid.

Comment: I just fixed it xD lets see if he accepts the edit

Comment: thanks for the edit guys, yes, I want to replace/permute the value of the concerned td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var cell0,
    cell1,
    next,
    row0,
    row1;

$('td').on('click', function() {
  if(!cell0) {
    cell0 = this;
    row0 = cell0.parentNode;
    return;
  } else if(!cell1) {
    cell1 = this;
    row1 = cell1.parentNode;

    // === Switch cells ===
    next = cell0.nextSibling;
    row1.insertBefore(cell0, cell1);
    row0.insertBefore(cell1, next);
    // ====================

    row0 = row1 = cell0 = cell1 = next = null;
  }
});
```

Working example you can try here: http://jsbin.com/irapeb/3/edit

Click one of the cells, than another one and see they are switched :)

Comment: thx man, but I realized that I don't need to permute the td but only their value, so that when I have the numbers in the right order (1234...) it triggers an event. So I'd like to simply change the html value of the td. Look at my code, I did it with jquery, but for some reason, I got a bug with the permutation after the first one. Do you have any idea why does that happen ?

Comment: You can't use `this.movecell` since it will be called in the scope of jQuery callback function and `this` will be `window` in that case. Your code has a bug - you called arguments of `movecell` same as global variables, thus you nullify these arguments and not the global vars.

Comment: that was it. But I don't understand what happen to c1 and c2 when I have them from this `movecell: function(c1,c2)` are they global variables here or just inside the fct ? I just edited my answer again

Answer (score 1):

This code will move the 4th `td` (referenced as `cell[3]`) on place of the first cell (`cell[0]`) in the first row (and the 1st becomes the 4th):

```
function moveCell(row, c1, c2) {
    var cell = row.cells;
        arr = [c1, c2].sort(),
        c1 = arr[1],
        c2 = arr[0];
    row.insertBefore(row.insertBefore(cell[c1], cell[c2]).nextSibling, cell[c1].nextSibling);
}

var row = $('table tr:nth-child(1)')[0];
moveCell(row, 0, 3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2N2rS/3/

I wrote this function to simplify process. It uses native table methods.

Modifying the number of row (`:nth-child(1)`) and indexes of the table cells you can permute them as you need.

Comment: Thanks,I'm more familiar with jQuery. Is there a way to do it with jQuery ?

Comment: In this case jQuery will not give a lot of advantages. Select necessary row in the table and pass it with `td` indexes to the function I wrote.

Comment: got it, Well I'm doing `$('td').on('click',function() { //move cell });` but how to wait for the second button to be clicked ? Thx

Comment: What buttons are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery, you can do it with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("table.table tbody tr td:first-child").each(function(index, element) {
    // this and element is the same    
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
    });

});
```

Assuming you don't ommited the tbody element (which is automatically added by some browser as default behaviour)

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EhQy4/1/)

If you want to do the process when clicking on the first cell, you just have to use `on` with click event instead of each.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("table.table tbody tr td:first-child").on('click', function(clickEvent) {
        $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to select a cell when clicking on it, so i guess I would use onclick or on('click') but I don't really know how

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in pure javascript:

1. Fetch clicked sell count;
2. Fetch data of both cells, when they are selected;
3. Replace cell values with the opposite ones;
4. Store new values in DB via ajax call.

Now it's up to you to write the script.